# Does adding columns to a stored procedure have performance risks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some instances where I'm pulling nearly identical information with slightly different formatting for web pages (A list of users with the first and last nnames separated into individual columns, for example, that are instead a single value of "Lastname, Firstname" elsewhere).  I'm thinking of how to reduce the amount of stored procedures I have to maintain and I was thinking about having a procedure that had both (so in the above example: first name, last name, and then "combinedname" or something).  But I'm wary about doing that if it will produce speed or performance issues.  obviously with the small pool of users I'm working with right now (less than 40), the speed differences would be small.  But if I had thousands would this significantly increase the time it takes for the query to execute?

Comment: The amount of data transferred over the wire can definitely affect performance. But if you're talking about 70 characters instead of 80, that's not that significant. And "FirstName", "LastName", "FullName" is pretty typical info, though usually "FullName" is something other than "FirstName" plus space plus "LastName". If it's just the latter, you can just do that on the client side and avoid doubling your data payload.

Comment: Wouldn't concatenation of the values on the client side (which is to say inside the controller pulling the information) have it's own performance issues?  Does this mean it's better to keep these as separate stored procedures?

Comment: Concatenation on the client side distributes the work involved to the clients, rather than having the single (usually) database server concatenating for every client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You real problem would be the maintainability of your code.  Every change to that single procedure would be high risk, as it would touch so many things.  But to answer your question, it can really depend on the column.  Calculated fields are anyone's guess depending what is being done, and if you have to add case statements to account for slightly different situations, you are def. going to add cycles.  Plus you would probably have a bigger execution plan to cache than you needed most times.